# How to delete a bone by script?

Tags: python, scripting, armature

MY Code:

```py
import bpy

bpy.data.objects["Armature"].select_set(True)

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Armature']

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
         
obj=bpy.context.object 

bone=obj.pose.bones["something"]

if bone is not None:
    
   obj.pose.bones.remove(bone)

   bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

Then it shows up this error message

```py
AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

Comment: Hello, Lathander, this does look like a duplicate. If for any reason the linked answer isn't satisfactory, edit this one explaining why, and we can re-open it for you.